# Why isn't my PHP code returning json data to my Ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm testing using AJAX to login to Wordpress. But my PHP code is not returning data to my ajax script.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

My template looks like this

```
// This code is at the top of my template

function authenticate($username, $password) {
    global $user;

    $data = array();
    $data['user_login'] = $username;
    $data['user_password'] =  $password;
    $data['remember'] = false;

    $user = wp_signon( $data, false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        $result = array('login' => false, 'error' => $user->get_error_message());
    }
    if ( !is_wp_error($user) ) {
        $result = array('login' => true);
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['user_login'])) {
    authenticate($_REQUEST['user_login'], $_REQUEST['user_password']);
}

(...) // My HTML starts here

<form name="loginform" action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
(...)
</form>
```

And this is my JS code

```
$('.login-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form       = $('form');
    var form_action = $form.attr('action');
    var form_data   = {
        'user_login': $form.find('.user_login').val(),
        'user_password': $form.find('.user_psw').val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form_action,
        data: form_data,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result){
            cl(result); // <-- This is not outputting anything
        }
    });
});
```

I'm probably just missing something fundamental here, but not sure what.

Comment: `cl(result); // <-- This is not outputting anything` — is the functino being called at all? Why don't you have an `error` function too? What *is* reported on the Developer Tools console? What does the Dev Tools Network tab say? Can you see the request? Does it get the proper response?

Comment: You should consider using AJAX properly, by using `wp_ajax_` action hooks and callbacks in *functions.php*: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: cl() is a custom function (shortcut) for `console.log()`. I'm using it for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding AJAX callbacks to *functions.php*, not a page template.

```
function so_34356392_ajax_auth() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['user_login'])) {
        authenticate($_REQUEST['user_login'], $_REQUEST['user_password']);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_so_34356392_auth', 'so_34356392_ajax_auth' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_so_34356392_auth', 'so_34356392_ajax_auth' );


function authenticate($username, $password) {
    global $user;

    $data = array();
    $data['user_login'] = $username;
    $data['user_password'] =  $password;
    $data['remember'] = false;

    $user = wp_signon( $data, false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
        $result = array('login' => false, 'error' => $user->get_error_message());
    }
    if ( !is_wp_error($user) ) {
        $result = array('login' => true);
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
    wp_die();  // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

And then your AJAX function would change to:

```
var form_data   = {
    'action': 'so_34356392_auth',  // Target the callback in functions.php
    'user_login': $form.find('.user_login').val(),
    'user_password': $form.find('.user_psw').val(),
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form_action,
    data: form_data,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result){
        cl(result);
    },
    error: function() {
        cl('Cannot retrieve data.');
    }
});
```

Read more about using AJAX in WordPress, [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Great @mevius, that's more I like it. But what would the URL be for the Ajax call?

Comment: @Steven , good question. It really depends on where your JS is. Are you including it directly in your page template? Or is it an external / separate .js file?

Comment: I've got separate JSfile. So I have to use this in the footer of my template: `<script type="text/javascript">var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';</script>`.

Comment: That's correct. So `url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (isset($_REQUEST['user_login'])) {
>     authenticate($_REQUEST['user_login'], $_REQUEST['user_password']);
> }
>
> (...) // My HTML starts here
> ```

You are outputting your JSON, but you are also outputting your HTML immediately afterwards. That makes the JSON invalid. This should have been warned about by one of the arguments that would have been passed to the `error` function, had you had one.

You need to output the HTML only if you aren't outputting the JSON.

Putting `exit()` inside the `if` statement would do the job (although I'd refactor things to have two distinct files to handle the different kinds of output and include different ones based on the `if` … or go a step further and use a full MVC framework).

You have also forgotten to set `header("Content-Type: application/json");` when you are outputting JSON.

Comment: ok, thanks. I started by having it in a separate PHP file, but then I didn't have access to the WP function.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['user_login'])) {
    // |-- you need an echo
    echo authenticate($_REQUEST['user_login'], $_REQUEST['user_password']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: "// |-- you need an echo" — Why? The `authenticate` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: This code (although not the echo statement) does actually fix the problem, but it doesn't *explain* how, and the explanation that is there is wrong and misleading.